# Add new item in Custom project type

Tags: visual-studio, project-types

I created a project type in visual studio as described in the Microsoft walk-through, but I couldn't add some item template to the "Add New Item" menu of this project type. Anyone could help me and tell me how can I perform this task?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out this tutorial, he even provides example code

http://www.kendar.org/?p=/tutorials/vsextensions/introduction

Basic idea:

- create an Item Template
- Import into VSIX project
- Specificy the location of the the project type